# Pass string/array argument and fill each, a variable in a function

Tags: php

Is there a way of passing an array or a string to a function dynamically and make each 'value' fill a different spot?

Suppose we have a function like this:

```
function test(){
    // Some code that can't be changed
    print_r(func_get_args()); // code-to-test-only
}
```

The expected result is:

> Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar )

```
// Simulated input to get expected result
// test('foo', 'bar');
```

And here are some examples - and their output - that didn't work:

```
test(array('foo', 'bar')); // Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar ) )
test(implode(',', array('foo', 'bar'))); // Array ( [0] => foo,bar )
test(explode(',', 'foo,bar')); // Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar ) )
```

Can this be achieved from **outside** of the function? I mean, can we get the expected result **without** changing the function at all?

Comment: `print_r(current(func_get_args()))`? or `print_r(func_get_args()[0])`?

Comment: @u_mulder that does provide the expected result when the argument is an array. But it requires changing the function itself. That way, any other logic could be used to break the _one_ argument. I'll edit the question...

Comment: Maybe you clarify the purpose of that? And the will be another solution.

Comment: @u_mulder, please, bare in mind that it's not an XY problem ^^. The question is pretty much that one..

Comment: Can we use function *parameterResolver* (like service OptionsResovler or ExressionLangauge) which receive this input and convert to expect and so put it there ?

Comment: `call_user_func_array('test', array('foo', 'bar'));`

Comment: I mean that we use function test(){
    $param = parametersResovler((func_get_args());
} so it will not changed after. All logic inside parametersResovler

Comment: @Rinat wouldn't that change the function? Because we'd still need to call the 'resolver'. We can't add nor remove anything from it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved with [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), like so:

```
// unchanged function
function test(){
    // Some code that can't be changed
    print_r(func_get_args()); // code-to-test-only
}

call_user_func_array('test', array('foo', 'bar'));
call_user_func_array('test', array('foo', 'bar', '123'));
```

And the output, as expected:

> Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar ) 
>   Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => 123 )

Thanks @u_mulder